# NotSerializableException when classes implement Serializable

Tags: java, android, serialization

## TL;DR

I get a java.io.NotSerializableException when I try to de-serialize a PullSheet object (classes below). Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: After adding an empty constructor to the problem class I am now getting an "incompatible" exception.

StackTrace:

```
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:606)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1772)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
com.campusden.learning.movingdata.ScannerActivity.loadSheet(ScannerActivity.java:271)
com.campusden.learning.movingdata.ScannerActivity.onCreate(ScannerActivity.java:79)
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

## The Problem

I am trying to serialize a PullSheet object so that a simple backup of data is stored and as a functional requirement for users. I am able to serialize the object without exception, but when I try to deserialize I get a java.io.NotSerializableException on the PullItem class.

## The Code

PullSheet.java

```
import ...

public class PullSheet implements Serializable{

protected String pullerName;
protected String role;
protected String store;
protected String sheetId;
protected String runItId;
protected String date;
protected UUID uuid;
protected String serialName;
protected Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
protected ArrayList<PullItem> SheetItems = new ArrayList<PullItem>();


public void createSheet(String _pullerName, String _role, String _store, String _runItId){
    setPullerName(_pullerName);
    setRole(_role);
    setStore(_store);
    setRunItId(_runItId);
    setSerialName();
    setDate();
    setUuid();
    setSheetId();
}

protected void addItem(String sku, Integer qty){
    SheetItems.add(new PullItem(sku, qty));
}
protected void removeItem(PullItem item){
    this.SheetItems.remove(item);
}

//Getters and setters

public String getPullerName(){ return pullerName; }
public String getRole(){ return role; }
public String getStore(){ return store; }
public String getRunItId(){ return runItId; }
public String getSheetId(){ return sheetId; }
public Long getStartTime(){ return startTime; }
public UUID getUuid() { return uuid; }


private void setPullerName(String _pullerName){ pullerName = _pullerName; }
private void setRole(String _role){ pullerName = _role; }
private void setStore(String _store){ store = _store; }
private void setRunItId(String _runItId){ runItId = _runItId; }
private void setSerialName(){ serialName = this.store + "-" + this.date + "_" + this.uuid; }
private void setUuid(){ uuid = UUID.randomUUID(); }
private void setDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    this.date = formatter.format(new Date(this.startTime));
}

private void setSheetId(){

    String randUUID = uuid.toString();
    sheetId = this.date + "-" + this.store + "-" + this.pullerName + "-" + randUUID + "-" + this.runItId;

}

}
```

PullItem.java

```
import ...

public class PullItem implements Serializable {

protected String sku;
protected Integer qty;


public PullItem(String sku, Integer qty) {
    setSku(sku);
    setQty(qty);
}

public PullItem(String sku) {
    setSku(sku);
    this.qty = 1;
}


String getSku(){
    return sku;
}

Integer getQty(){
    return qty;
}

void setSku(String _sku){
    sku = _sku;
}

void setQty(Integer _qty){
    qty = _qty;
}
void incrementQty(){
    qty += 1;
}
}
```

The functions that serialize and deserialize the PullSheet object:

```
public static boolean saveSheet(Context context, PullSheet sheet){
    String fileName = "saved.szs";
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        Log.d("rep", fileName);
        oos.writeObject(sheet);
        oos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static PullSheet loadSheet(Context context, String fileName) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Object readObject = is.readObject();
        is.close();

        if(readObject != null && readObject instanceof PullSheet) {
            return (PullSheet) readObject;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

## What I Need

Please let me know where I'm going wrong. I assume it's not the types that are causing the exception because all the classes implement Serializable, but I could be off. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Could you try to define an empty constructor

Comment: Are you passing a subclass of `PullSheet`?

Comment: "I get a java.io.NotSerializableException" -- please edit your question and provide the complete Java stack trace associated with this exception.

Comment: Adding the empty constructor added "local class incompatible: stream classdsc serialversionUID = x

Comment: @CommonsWare see edit: stackTrace added. Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting the error in loadSheet() method? or in saveSheet() method?

Comment: Loadsheet method is throwing the exception

Comment: @Debanjan That question is answered by the stack trace.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked, its in readObject. So it may be possible, that you are trying to load something that you have previously saved, and after that you have added some variable or since you have not defined a serialVersionUUID, the object cannot be deserialized, may be because the serialVersionUUID calculated now is different from the previous ones.

Comment: @Debanjan That would cause an [`InvalidClassException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InvalidClassException.html), not `NotSerializableException`.

Comment: @OlivierTerrien Try it why? Serializable objects don't need empty constructors.

Comment: @EJP : Yes you are right. It is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It didn't implement `Serializable` when you serialized it. You got an exception at that time. You fixed it to implement `Serializable`. Then you tried to deserialize the old stream. It doesn't work.

**EDIT**

> After adding an empty constructor to the problem class I am now getting an "incompatible" exception.

Because you changed the implicit `serialVersionUID`. You don't need an empty constructor in a `Serializable` class.

**EDIT 2**

Some folk here appear to be unaware that when you attempt to serialize a non-serializable object, a `NotSerializableException` is (1) thrown and (2) written into the data stream in such a way that when you reach it when reading with `readObject()`, it is thrown again, exactly as shown in the OP's stack trace.

Comment: That would give an incompatible exception (don't remember the exact name), NotSerializableException is when you try to serialize something you can't serialize

Comment: This was exactly the problem. You must have esp, buut I forgot that I had saved data before I remembered to implement serializable on my PullItems. A million thanks!

Comment: @LunarWatcher After I added an empty constructor it did give the incompatible exception, Forgot to edit that into the question.

Comment: @mtrueblood I do not have ESP. The fact that it occurred during `readObject()` rather than `writeObject()` told me all that.

Comment: @LunarWatcher In other words you haven't tried it. Do so before you debate this further.